# How do I show that the definition of boundary in a metric space is equivalent to the definition of boundary in a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Show that the the definition of the boundary of a subset E
> of metric space X,  $\partial S : = \{p \in X: \forall r>0, E \cap B_r(p) \neq \emptyset \text{ and } E^C \cap B_r(p) \neq \emptyset \}$
> is equivalent to the definition of the boundary in case of a set E in
> the topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, $\partial S := \overline{E} \setminus E^0$

Attempted solution:

Let $C := \{p \in X: \forall r>0, E \cap B_r(p) \neq \emptyset \text{ and } E^C \cap B_r(p) \neq \emptyset \}$ and $D := \overline{E}\setminus E^0$. In order to show $C = D$, we need to first show that for any $x \in C \text{ implies } x \in D$ and then show that for any $x \in D \text{ implies } x \in C$.

Let $x \in C$. Then, $E \cap B_r(x) \neq \emptyset$ and $E^C \cap B_r(x) \neq \emptyset$. Consider an arbitrary set $F_\alpha$ such that $F_\alpha$ is a closed subset in $X$ and $E \subseteq F_\alpha$. Now , I need to show that $x \in F_\alpha$ ,  which implies that $x \in \bigcap_{\alpha} F_\alpha = \overline{E}$, but I have no idea how to do this.

Next,  I need to show that $x \notin E^0$. I am assuming we do a proof by contradiction but I am not really sure how to proceed.

Also, I have no idea on how to proceed in the reverse directions. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in C$, then every ball around $x$ intersects $E$, therefore $x\in\overline{E}$, however no ball around $x$ is contained inside $E$, hence $x\notin E^0$.

Conversely, if $x\in D$, then $x\in \overline{E}$, so every ball around $x$ intersects $E$. At the same time, $x\notin E^0$, hence no ball is contained inside $E$. In other words, for every $r>0$, $B_r(x)\cap E\neq \emptyset$ and because $B_r(x)\not\subseteq E$ we have $B_r(x)\cap E^c\neq\emptyset$.